# In java, a method call that I expect to return a value that must be captured is not throwing a compile error. Why?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

In Java, if a method definition returns something, the class that calls that method must prepare to capture the return value of that method into a variable. Atleast that's what I understand logically. But I have a weird situation in which the compiler is not complaining.

I have an Animal interface with methods defined. An AnimalImpl class that implements the Animal interface, and Lion class that uses composition for an instance variable of type Animal.

here's the code. why is the compiler not going berserk?

*Interface:*

```
public interface Animal {
    public int walk(int steps);
    public int fly(int miles);
    public void eat(String food);   
}
```

*Implementation:*

```
public class AnimalImpl implements Animal {
    @Override
    public int walk(int steps) {

        return steps * 100;
    }
    @Override
    public int fly(int miles) {
        return miles/5;
    }
    @Override
    public void eat(String food) {
        System.out.println("Animal ate food: "+food);

    }
}
```

*Client:*

```
public class Lion {
    private Animal ani;
    public String executeAnimalMethod(){
        ani = new AnimalImpl();
        ani.eat("carrots");
        ani.walk(100);
        ani.fly(100);
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can the compiler not throw an error? Why is this the case?

Comment: Compile errors are not thrown, they are printed.

Comment: In Java (as in C) it's perfectly legit to ignore the return parm of a method call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a language requirement that the value returned from a method be used.

This situation happens routinely and frequently, eg:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
set.add(1); // returned boolean ignored
```

[`Set#add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) returns a boolean value indicating if the set was changed as a result of calling it with the given parameter (returns false if the set already contained the value), but most of the time the returned value is ignored as in the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to store a return value in a variable.  Just because it's returned doesn't mean you have to keep it around.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is not error'ing because everything you wrote is legal java.

You did not say in your question where specifically you thought the compiler should error at.  Without knowing more, I can assume you think that just because a method has a return type that the caller of that method must assign it to something.  Java does not enforce that at all - a client of a class may call a method and completely ignore its return value legally.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I have never seen anyone so distraught about *not* getting errors.

First, Java doesn't force you to capture the value returned from a method.

Second, not all Java methods even return a value. Some are `void`.

It just happens that you often need to capture return values to do other things, but you don't have to.

Don't worry. If you are anything like me, your compiler and your runtime log will be going berserk soon enough. Enjoy it while it lasts.

Comment: Thanks I'm new to this whole compiled languages world. I come from a scripting language background. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help. Note though that one can argue over the merits, but it is legal to not capture the result from a Python or Ruby function either. The difference with Java is that their functions always return something (None in Python, nil in Ruby).